# Function atoi returns wrong number

Tags: c

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main (void) {

//------------------------ Variaveis------------------------//
    char num[2];
    int aux1, aux2, aux3;

//------------------------Parte grafica---------------------//
    printf ("Escreva um numero de 0 a 99: ");
    scanf ("%s", &num);
    printf("\nEste numero por extenso eh: ");

//-------------------------Conversão------------------------//
    aux1 = atoi(num);
    aux2 = atoi(&num[0]);
    aux3 = atoi(&num[1]);
```

Don't mind the language, the point is, if you type a number like "56" for scanf to read for example, aux2 gets the value of "56" instead of "5" that I wanted, and aux3 gets the value of "6" which is actually what I expected. What is wrong with aux2?

Comment: Can you say what you believe `&num[0]` means?  Because I think it does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @jwdonahue "duplicate" doesn't mean "some other vaguely related question on a similar topic"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you fix undefined behavior by adding space for null terminator, let's consider behavior of your program.

> What is wrong with `aux2`?

Since `atoi` considers the whole string, `aux2` is the same as `aux`, because it's the string starting at `'5'` and continuing to `'\0'`.

If you wanted to get the individual digits, use subtraction of `'0'`:

```
int aux2 = num[0] - '0';
int aux3 = num[1] - '0';
```

Make sure that `num` has exactly two characters, and both characters are digits.

Comment: Now I can finally get an idea about the null terminator behavior, thanks for this and all the answers

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior as you dont have space of null terminator when you enter 2 digit numeric value as string in char `num[3];`

Change it to char num[3] and take input as:

```
scanf ("%2s", num);
```

When you print

```
printf("%d %d %d\n",aux1,aux2,aux3); // for input 56
```

You would get 56 56 6
The reason is `num` and `&num[0]` are same, they point to same address where as `&num[1]` would point to next address so you get 6 there

Comment: This is true, but the OP would have the same problem if he were using an adequately dimensioned array.  His expectations are wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger added explaination for it